# looping through 2 array to find out which checkboxes should be checked

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have 2 arrays, $categories_filters and $adds_filters. They both return results. When printed using print_r, they return data in following format:

$categories_filters returns data like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [filterid] => 67
        [catid] => 1
        [filtername] => FILTERNAME1
        [sorder] => 1
        [visible] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [filterid] => 68
        [catid] => 1
        [filtername] => FILTERNAME155
        [sorder] => 2
        [visible] => 1
    )
    .....
```

$adds_filters returns the following:

```
  Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [addfilterid] => 9
        [addid] => 5
        [filterid] => 67
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [addfilterid] => 10
        [addid] => 5
        [filterid] => 163
    )

)....
```

I am trying the following:
I have checkbox for each value in the $categories_filters. If the filterid exists in the $adds_filters array, i want that checkbox to be checked, otherwise, i want that checkbox just to be displayed unchecked.

I am trying to achieve that with the following code:

```
if($categories_filters) {
    foreach ($categories_filters as $key1=>$value){
        echo "<div class='chb_group'>";
        echo "<span class='custom_chb_wrapper'>";
        foreach ($adds_filters as $key2=>$af) {
            if($af['filterid'] == $value['filterid']) {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='categoriesfilters[]' id= '".$value['filterid']."'  value='" .$value['filterid'] ."'  checked = 'checked' class='zcheckbox' />";    
            } else  {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='categoriesfilters[]' id= '".$value['filterid']."'  value='" .$value['filterid'] ."' class='zcheckbox' />";
            }
        } 
        echo "<label>" .$value['filtername']. "</label>";
        echo "</span>";
        echo "</div>"
    } 
}else {
    echo  "No filters"; 
}
```

Quick catchers will realize that I get 2 checkboxes displayed for each value in the arrays, instead of one (checked or unchecked)

I guess that different approach is needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion would be that instead of looping through the entire `$adds_filters` array everytime, store all the `'filterid'` into a variable and just check if the `$value['filterid']` exists inside that array.
The code below uses functions [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array) and [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map).
Try this -

```
if($categories_filters) {
    //Added this
    $addfilterids = array_map(function($v){return $v['filterid'];}, $adds_filters);

    foreach ($categories_filters as $key1=>$value){
        echo "<div class='chb_group'>";
        echo "<span class='custom_chb_wrapper'>";
        
        //Modified from here-
        if(in_array($value['filterid'], $addfilterids)){
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='categoriesfilters[]' id= '".$value['filterid']."'  value='" .$value['filterid'] ."'  checked = 'checked' class='zcheckbox' />";    
        }else{
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='categoriesfilters[]' id= '".$value['filterid']."'  value='" .$value['filterid'] ."' class='zcheckbox' />";
        }
        //^Modified uptil here.
        
        echo "<label>" .$value['filtername']. "</label>";
        echo "</span>";
        echo "</div>"
    } 
}
```

Comment: The above code do return all checkboxes only once, but none of them is checked. let me see if i can spot any mistake...

Comment: Basically I had compared 'addfilterid' and not 'filterid'. It should probably work now.